# How to apply "overflow-y:scroll" (vertical scroll) and "display:inline" both on a DIV

Tags: html, css

I have one requirement to show vertical scroll and textbox [TextBox_Inline_Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jKFJ.png) element should be inline on a DIV. I'm using overflow-y:scroll and display:inline both css properties on the DIV. I'm able to get the vertical scroll after certain height but when I remove disply:inline, Textbox element comes down in second line instead being there in same line.

I'have attached screen shot for the reference.

```
.header-section{
    max-height: 133px;
    /*display: inline;*/
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: can you add a full jsfiddle to see the problem?

Comment: Did you try using `display: inline-block`? https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/eyjpWW

Comment: @Danield, I tried with inline-block as well but it did not work. By default div is having display:block property set so If I use display:inline in my class, TextBox element comes in the same line but then I'm not able to see vertical scroll on the DIV.